How does this MAX7219 LED matrix driver IC circuit work? How should I use it?
I'm using a MAX7219 to drive an LED matrix, but the LEDs are too dim(For me! and in the daylight). I want the matrix to be brighter. Here is the MAX7219 IC:


I searched and found this page and they recommend three ways. The first one works for me. Now my problem is that I don't understand this circuit and how should I apply it to my design. Here is the first recommended method for Digit Drivers.

The simplest circuit (Figure 1) suits an application where a higher than 40mA segment current is desired, and yet the 4V-5V MAX7219/7221 supply voltage can be used to drive the LEDs. The active low MAX7219/7221 digit drive outputs directly drive logic level PFET Q2. Resistor R3 turns Q2 off when the digit output is high impedance. The supply Vdriver is the same supply as used by the MAX7219/7221.


and here a method for Segment Drivers:

The MAX7219/7221 segment drive outputs are current sources, which drive a constant current set by resistor RSET connected to the ISET pin of the MAX7219/7221. The maximum segment current is 40mA. To drive a higher segment current, external transistors and segment current limiting resistors are needed .


UPDATE:
it seems that my previously somehow correct circuit was ok, but here is the correct one based on this post:

Now, my question is that will it work on my matrix? one transistor and one MOSFET for each row and column of the matrix?

Maybe you should post what circuit you used when it was very dim, including Rset value, what register settings you used, and what make and model LED display you have connected - or at least colour of the display, and what VCC supply voltage you used. For example the circuit or register settings may have been wrong, or the LED display is incompatible for some reason, and it could be too dim even with new circuit. Also, your FETs are connected incorrectly so it would not work.

"The first one works for me. Now my problem is that I don't understand this circuit and how should I apply it to my design" So how do you know it works for you?

@Justme my led matrix is a custom made 8x8 white LED (3.3vdc and around 25 milliamp).  the Rest value is set to minimum 10K as it was recommended in datasheet. In the link it was mentioned that each segment has 40mA current, this is not enough for my use, and sorry about my circuit, it needs more explanation, I edited the question, it is my new design based on the provided link.

@MOSFET "The simplest circuit (Figure 1) suits an application where a higher than 40mA segment current is desired, and yet the 4V-5V MAX7219/7221 supply voltage can be used to drive the LEDs." I need more than  40mA and my supply voltage is 5VDC!

@TRY Are your segments common anode or common cathode? Also, you are presenting the wrong transistors in your design - ap note circuit 1 is using P-MOSFETs. You are showing N-MOSFETs. Your transistors will always be conducting. Also, what is total voltage drop (per channel) of your >40mA LED(s)?

@MOSFET there is no common anode or common cathode. there are 8 DIG's and 8 SEG's in MAX7219. FDN360P is a P−Channel MOSFET. Please at least read the datasheets before further questions.

@TRY You wired it wrong in your circuit. Please try to get the schematic right before asking for help.

@MOSFET TNX, it's now edited.

From your comment: "my led matrix is a custom made 8x8 white LED (3.3vdc and around 25 milliamp)" implies you don't have to add any current-boost circuitry as the LED controller is good for up to 40mA/channel.
But if you still insist on overdriving your LED's, and you are stuck with a 5V supply voltage, just do it this way:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
R3 sets the LED current. Adjust this for your LED's and how hard you want to overdrive them. R1 and R5 may be optional depending on leakage and and gain factors (the LEDs might not go to "perfectly off" without them). If you have PCB space, include them anyway if you are unsure.
Q1 is (ahem) COMMON for all the segment (ANODES) for a given digit. You will need a PNP transistor for each "digit" group.
Q2 is (ahem) COMMON for all the digit (CATHODES) for a given segment. You will need an NPN transistor for each "segment" group.
You can use MOSFETS as shown in the app note. But I find them more expensive, harder to drive at logic-levels, and harder to procure. Although I haven't shopped for logic-level, small-signal fets in a while, availability may be different these days.

Have you bothered to read the datasheet for MAX7219? there are no common anodes nor common cathodes!

@TRY I'm sorry. I didn't read the datasheet at first - I didn't need to read it. You do need to read and understand it and you clearly didn't.  7th bullet down under features "Drive Common-Cathode LED Display". Do you even understand what that means? You lack experience to be correcting others and your ego shows. Check yourself before you look silly.

I told you that I made a custom made 8x8 and there are no common anodes nor common cathodes in my design! and you keep insisting on that! and look "@TRY I'm sorry. I didn't read the datasheet at first " and now I wonder whose "ego shows."! TNX for your help.

@TRY Actually, that statement comes from the datasheet that you didn't read. I'm not insisting on anything. You still don't understand the significance of my questioning which is exactly why you are having trouble with the circuitry needed for higher current. The only way you can possibly be wiring your 8x8 LED array is common-anode or common anode. It's one or the other. The chip you are using has a common ground with open-collector outputs. Please post your LED arrangement that DOESN'T correspond to a common anode or common cathode arrangement. I'm very interested in your novel LED design...

@TRY Just look at your LED matrix - each column is a single common cathode for each "digit" and each row is a current source for each "segment" in each column/digit. That's the way it is and please don't argue and insist about not having common cathodes - your matrix is no different from having 8 digits of 7-segment displays (with decimal point) if you just want to light up arbitrary LEDs in a matrix.

TNX but let's suppose this method works fine but compared to the recommended method in link that I provided, it has too many extra components. I have found the correct circuit, yet I don't know if its work for my matrix. I have updated the question.

@TRY What I posted vs what's in the app note has exactly the same component count. The only difference is I'm using a PNP transistor instead of a MOSFET. R1 and R5 may be optional. That's the best you can do regrading component count. It's still not clear why you even need this circuitry. Your using 25mA LEDs and the driver is good for 40mA - much more than the LEDs can reliably handle.
